Showing a divisibility related number theory problem
The problem is the following:
Let x,y and z be positive integers such that: $$x^{2}+y^{2}= 3×(2023)^{z}+77$$

Prove that if 4 divides $x^{2}+y^{2}$ then it divides both $x$ and $y$. I could easily prove that by contradiction.
Prove that if 7 divides $x^{2}+y^{2}$, then it divides both $x^{2}$ and $y^{2}$. I could Prove that too by letting $x=7k+r$ and $y=7t+r'$ then showing 7 has to divide $r^{2}+r'^{2}$ hence $r=r'=0$.
Conclude the solutions to the given Diophantine equation. That's where I'm stuck, I don't know how I can use what I've proved earlier. Note that I'm not allowed to use modular arithmetic


FYI, I found the duplicate using an Approach0 search. There's also the AoPS thread Diophantine equation, and $x^{2}+y^{2}=3(2023)^{z}+77$: to prove that if $4 \mid x^{2}+y^{2} \implies 4\mid x^{2},y^{2}$ which asks about only one part of the problem.

Re: your edit saying "I'm not allowed to use modular arithmetic".  Where did that constraint come from? It would be pedagogically foolish to give someone a problem like this before they have learned modular arithmetic.
